# Like button - Toggle between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to toggle between two functions when a "Like" button is clicked.

```
 <div class="like">
  <div class="count"><%= post.num_likes %> </div>
  <div class="icon" id="like"><i class="icon-thumbs-up-alt"></i></div>
</div>
```

right now I have:

```
$(".like").click(function(event){       
event.stopPropagation();                    
$("i", this).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt").toggleClass("icon icon-thumbs-up");                           
 likePost(TestCanvas, $(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text());    
 });
```

likePost(canvasID, postID) takes parameters and interacts with an API
When I click on .like again, I would like to call unlikePost().

Is there an easy way to toggle between likePost() and unlikePost() when .like is clicked?

Ive tried:

```
$('.like').toggle(function() {
 alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
 likePost(TestCanvas, $(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text());
}, function() {
alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
unlikePost(TestCanvas, $(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text());
});
```

Its not working as i thought it would though. Seems to execute on page load instead of on click of .like.

Comment: Well, since you are applying a class, you could check for the existence of that class with the `hasClass` method.

Comment: the `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.9

Comment: Thanks to you too friend for asking same questing that I was searching since long ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toggle a class. Than by reading if the element has such class - you can deduce if the user liked or removed it's like:

```js
$('.like').click(function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  $(this).toggleClass('is-liked');
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-liked')) {
    val++
    // User has liked (insert userId, itemId into Likes table)
  } else {
    val--
    // User removed his like (delete from table Likes where userId and itemId)
  }
  
  $(this).text(val);
});
```

```css
.like {
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #0bf;
  font-weight: bold;
  user-select: none;
}
.like:after {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.is-liked {
  background: #0bf;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="like">0</span>
<span class="like is-liked">3</span>
<span class="like">6</span>
<span class="like">12</span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a "liked" class when liked.

```
$('.like').on('click', function() {
  if $(this).hasClass("liked") {
    //do unlike
    $(this).removeClass("liked");
  }
  else {
    //do like
    $(this).addClass("liked");
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the `myBool` doing there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an element's own data to store the current state of the toggle using `$(this).data()`.  This will allow many instances of your `.like` elements to work independently.

(Generally speaking I dislike using `class` values to represent actual program state.  IMHO, classes are for styling, not logic).

Since your two functions have the same parameters you can also just obtain a reference to the desired function based on the current state and then call it:

```
$(".like").on('click', function(event) {
    // from OP's code
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt icon icon-thumbs-up");

    // extract and toggle state (first click _sets_ state to "truthy")
    var data = $(this).data();
    data.state ^= 1;

    // determine which function to call, then call it - DRY
    var fn = data.state ? likePost : unlikePost;
    fn(TestCanvas, $(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text());
});
```

Comment: @adeneo It's an "exclusive or assigment" - roughly equivalent in this case to `data.state = !data.state`, but shorter.  Strictly speaking it creates `0` or `1` values instead of `false` and `true`, though.

Comment: Aha, so it would return one or zero based on wether or not data.state is truthy / falsy, which again is thruthy / falsy (one or zero). Haven't seen that used like that before.

Comment: And you've added it to the comment, I get it!

Comment: @adeneo I like it because it avoids the repetition of the operand on both sides of the operator.

Comment: +1, hadn't seen that one before, but I like it, will have to steal that as I quite often do the `var = !var` thing

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but this should do what you want I think.

```
var myBool = true;
$('.like').on('click', function() {
  if (myBool) {
    //function 1 here
  }
  else {
    //function 2 here
  }
  myBool = !myBool;
});
```

Edit:  Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLua2/).

Comment: This is assuming you only have one like button though.

Answer (score 0):

Use one class to find if content was liked or not:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(evt){
          evt.preventDefault();
          if( $(this).is('liked') ){
            $(this).removeClass('liked');
            doUnlike();
          }
          else{
            $(this).addClass('liked');
            dolike();
          }
       }
     doUnlike(){
     //...
     }
     dolike(){
     //.....
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since toggleClass would be switching in adding and removing class which is kind of work around anyway. And creating a variable is unsuitable for multiple buttons. You can hide a variable in a hidden input tag inside of the div/button and access it with find function. Script will be switching values and it will create wished toggle effect since toggle function does not support two functions anymore and is only used for hide and show.

Another possibility:

```
<div class="like">
    <input type="hidden" value=0 />
    One
    <div class="display"></div>
</div>
<div class="like">
    <input type="hidden" value=0 />
    Two
    <div class="display"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(".like").click(function() {
        var tagvar = "input[type='hidden']";
        if ( $(this).find(tagvar).val() == 0 ) {
            $(this).find(".display").html("yes");
            $(this).find(tagvar).val(1);
        }else {
            $(this).find(".display").html("no");
            $(this).find(tagvar).val(0);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any description ?

Comment: Since toggleClass would be switching in adding and removing class which is kind of work around anyway. And creating a variable is unsuitable for multiple buttons. You can hide a variable in a hidden input tag inside of the div/button and access it with find function. Script will be switching values and it will create wished toggle effect since toggle function does not support two functions anymore and is only used for hide and show.